# Who are we employees? And who do we work for?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

The generalised name of us employees is seven plus five letters long.

Our company's name is five plus five letters long.

Can you put your finger on what each of the following clues alludes to?

---

1. Our company started off in a single-story building, which was so catastrophically badly received by our customers for not having an ounce of originality. With that lesson in mind, we moved to a 28-story building, then to a 52-story high rise. We have learnt that multiple levels are indeed the key to moving our customers' hearts.
2. Female employees tend to occupy upper stories, while male employees prefer lower stories, including basement levels.
3. Upon entering the lobby of our company's building, you will first be greeted by a huge curly object soaring several stories above, and then our receptionist (the first of our employees you meet) will welcome you. The thing is, you will not necessarily meet her on the first floor, but possibly on the 5th floor, or even on one of the basement levels. You'll never know. Not only that, you might even need to meet several receptionists at once, each waiting for your arrival on separate floors.
4. A sort of "director" in Room "3" alters some of our employees' nature, raising their spirits a little.
5. The elevator in our company is, how should I put it... "strange". It goes up normally until the 7th floor (American floor-counting style), but then, when reaching the 8th floor, we get this uncanny feeling, as if we had landed back on the first floor. Of course, this is just a figment of our imagination, and the elevator keeps going up until the top floor.
6. Some of our employees are obligated to wear their ties, even in the heart of summer.
7. In our company, we always send messages from one employee to the next; we never cut corners and forward them to everyone at once.
8. Some of our employees send messages in no time flat, others take longer, while still others take much longer.
9. It is crucial that each of us transmits a message to a specific employee on a predetermined floor. Sending it to a wrong person on a different floor may end up disrupting the entire operation.
10. Some of our employees like to hang about at the landing of the stairs.
11. Our company's motto is to cater to the varying requirements of our customers, whether it be to calm their souls or energise them. In a bid to achieve this, our employees work closely in tandem with one another.

Comment: Is the answer a known concept to a layman or is it something that requires specific knowledge in some field of learning (past probably high school/secondary school if you are non-us)?

Comment: @Gordon Allocman        Hi. This riddle is related to a particular field, but no extensive knowledge is required.  Just some broad, general knowledge/concepts will more than cover it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The employees are

> Musical Notes

and the company is

> The Grand Staff

1. Our company started off in a single-story building, which was so catastrophically badly received by our customers for not having an ounce of originality. With that lesson in mind, we moved to a 28-story building, then to a 52-story high rise. We have learnt that multiple levels are indeed the key to moving our customers' hearts.

   > Musical notes used to written in one line, before multiple line staffs originated. Not sure about the 28 and 52... There are 52 white keys on a piano, so I suppose that could correlate to the 52 stories; though, piano music doesn't actually use 52 lines but rather denotes that notes are an octave (or several octaves) lower of higher than indicated.
2. Female employees tend to occupy upper stories, while male employees prefer lower stories, including basement levels.

   > Females generally sing the higher notes, males the lower. Some male notes will be written in a lower staff.

3a. Upon entering the lobby of our company's building, you will first be greeted by a huge curly object soaring several stories above,

> Possibly the brace, connecting the staffs.

3b. and then our receptionist (the first of our employees you meet) will welcome you. The thing is, you will not necessarily meet her on the first floor, but possibly on the 5th floor, or even on one of the basement levels. You'll never know. Not only that, you might even need to meet several receptionists at once, each waiting for your arrival on separate floors.

> The clefs. There can be several clefs on different staffs.

4. A sort of "director" in Room "3" alters some of our employees' nature, raising their spirits a little.

   > The 'sharp', which can 'raise' the pitch of a note. The "3" could refer to the fact that the 'sharp' symbol is located on the '3' key on the computer keyboard.
5. The elevator in our company is, how should I put it... "strange". It goes up normally until the 7th floor (American floor-counting style), but then, when reaching the 8th floor, we get this uncanny feeling, as if we had landed back on the first floor. Of course, this is just a figment of our imagination, and the elevator keeps going up until the top floor.

   > Describing the octave. You elevate from note to note, and every 8 notes you 'land back' on the base note, though are actually still rising in pitch.
6. Some of our employees are obligated to wear their ties, even in the heart of summer.

   > Musical notes can have a 'tie': http://piano.about.com/od/basicmusicalterms/g/GL_tie.htm
7. In our company, we always send messages from one employee to the next; we never cut corners and forward them to everyone at once.

   > Not sure. You play one note at a time (though some instruments can play several at once)?
8. Some of our employees send messages in no time flat, others take longer, while still others take much longer.

   > Different notes have different lengths: quarter, half, whole, etc.
9. It is crucial that each of us transmits a message to a specific employee on a predetermined floor. Sending it to a wrong person on a different floor may end up disrupting the entire operation.

   > Notes should represent a specific pitch.
10. Some of our employees like to hang about at the landing of the stairs.

    > Notes can be on the staff lines or in the space between the lines (between 'floors').
11. Our company's motto is to cater to the varying requirements of our customers, whether it be to calm their souls or energise them. In a bid to achieve this, our employees work closely in tandem with one another.

    > Music can have different emotions. The notes work with each other (in different ways) to account for the desired mood/sound.

Comment: To kayzeroshort: Hi. Actually, the company's name can be any of the following three: One is your answer, two is its British counterpart, and three is a more "generalised/broad" term for your answer. By a happy coincidence, any of the three matches the "5 + 5 letters long" criteria.